# How to get intersection of two lists in terraform?

Tags: terraform

I have two lists in terraform and want to get the intersection of these lists.

For example,

```
list1 = ["a", "b", "c"]
lists2 = ["b", "c", "d"]
```

I am looking to get output as `["b", "c"]` using built-in terraform functions.

Answer (score 2):

You are looking for something like this

```
 output my_intersection {
   value = setintersection( toset(var.list1), toset(var.list2) )
 }
```